# How save js color picker changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, save

I'v made a js color picker in my xenforo forum, and it works, but after reloading the page all the changes will be reset.
is there any way to save these changes?
js color picker: http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

my codes:

```
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
color: '#0000ff',
onShow: function (colpkr) {
    $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
    return false;
},
onHide: function (colpkr) {
    $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
    return false;
},
onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
    $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    $('.VietXfAdvStats h3').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [documentation](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/) you can do the following:

```
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
  onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
    doSomeThingToSave(hex);
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to set the `hex` value in a form input, but I can't help you without seeing the html code.

Comment: HTML: <div id="colorSelector"><div style="background-color: #0000ff"></div></div>

Comment: But do you have any form in which you can save the colorpicker value?

Comment: I dont know what to do. just have the js code and HTML above, and nothing more. I want to use this color picker as a style switcher for my background colors, but after reloading the page, the color will be reset.

Comment: Is the color change to be applied just for you, or is it a configuration for the whole forum to appear with the background color set to all users?

Comment: I want each user be able to select his/her favorite color . its now possible but it doesnt save the selected color . like the one in sahifa wp theme : http://themes.tielabs.com/?theme=sahifa